# Showing that the lattice D_4^+ is congruent to Z^4

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integer-lattices

I'm currently reading Conway and Sloane's *Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups*. It is a great read for facts, but they only sketch proofs at a high level.

Within it, they define the lattice $D_n$ to be the set of all points with even coordinates. Another similar collection of points is
$$D_n^+ = D_n \cup \left\{D_n+\vec{\frac{1}{2}}\right\}$$
One can show that this is a lattice only in even dimensions by noticing that $-\vec{1/2}$ can only be constructed in even dimensions. It is then stated without proof that this lattice is congruence to $\mathbb Z^4$ in 4 dimensions. I was wondering if anybody could provide a proof of this amazing fact? What about for other dimensions? I have found a basis with determinant 1, but the coefficients are rational, not integral.

Comment: I like Lattices and Codes by Ebeling

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks, I'll take a look. Do you know of a reference that is a good explanation for the genus and spinor of a lattice?

Comment: Well, what about the spinor genus?  For example, what dimension?  Meanwhile, I put a bunch of pdf's at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/  I generally recommend Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms.

Comment: @WillJagy This is perfect! Bhargava 2000 is exactly what I am trying to work towards understanding. Thanks for linking this, this is a treasure trove

Comment: In that case you would benefit from some tables at Nebe's http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/  icluding the ternary genera, Alexander Schiemann's tables, this one http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/Brandt_1.html  especially. Also see my notes http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Jagy_Encyclopedia.pdf   and Dickson(1939)  Modern Elementary Theory of Numbers  ///  and Jones (1950)  The Arithmetic Theory of Quadratic Forms /// and Watson(1960)  Integral Quadratic Forms and /// Cassels(1968)  Rational Quadratic Forms